# Why can't I create an object stemming from a drop method in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, methods

My columns in the CSV file I uploaded are A,B,C,D,E,F. 
I want to drop 'B', 'C' columns however I want to create 2 separate  data frame objects. 1 data frame object in its original form and a 2nd data frame object after I use the drop method. I get the following error:

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
data2 = data1.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1)
data2.head()
```

The error I get is:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 data2.head()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: please check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly with a sample input dataframe

Comment: Did you call the method like `data2.head()`? I don't see any 'NoneType' object in your code.

Comment: Did you even refer the links. How do we know what `data1.csv` looks like? you have to respect the forum which volunteers to help user's. Its the users responsibility to make the question reproducible so people dont have to spend their time to create an example .

Answer (score 0):

Inplace parameter was set to True for the drop method. This does not allow object to be created. It needed to be set to False.

Answer (score -1):

Lets us create a panda (pd) DataFrame and assign it to object1.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

create a list

```
lists = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
```

create columns names

```
columns = ['A','B','C','D']
```

create data frame and assign to object1

```
object1 = pd.DataFrame(lists, columns=columns)
```

Now drop the column B and C using dataframe.drop command and assign to object2

```
object2 = object1.drop(['B','C'], axis=1)
```

This works! hope it helps :). for more ways to create DataFrame with pd use this link https://www.ritchieng.com/creating-dataframe-from-objects/ and to drop columns https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: Hi Divya! You might want to format your answer more clearly to avoid getting downvotes. Take a look at  [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I hope the above edits are more readable